# Error installing multiqc from Conda (importlib-metadata)

Tags: bioinformatics

I am trying to install multiqc from bioconda using the following code.

`conda install -c bioconda multiqc`

When i check if it is installed, i get the following error.

````
(rnaseq) td@econ ~ % multiqc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tahadinc/opt/anaconda3/envs/rnaseq/bin/multiqc", line 4, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').run_script('multiqc==1.0.dev0', 'multiqc')
  File "/Users/tahadinc/opt/anaconda3/envs/rnaseq/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3242, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/Users/tahadinc/opt/anaconda3/envs/rnaseq/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3226, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/tahadinc/opt/anaconda3/envs/rnaseq/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3255, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/Users/tahadinc/opt/anaconda3/envs/rnaseq/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 568, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/Users/tahadinc/opt/anaconda3/envs/rnaseq/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 886, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/Users/tahadinc/opt/anaconda3/envs/rnaseq/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 772, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'importlib-metadata' distribution was not found and is required by click``` 

I tried to find a solution online, but I couldn't.
I would appreciate any help. 
Thank you
````

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create a new environment specifically for multiqc?

```
conda create --name multiqc -c bioconda multiqc
conda activate multiqc
```

There might be a conflict for *importlib-metadata* and another package in your rnaseq environment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not sure where the problem is arising from but I was able to solve it by installing the multiqc using the code below. 

`conda install -c bioconda -c conda-forge multiqc`

If i install using the code below I get the error i mentioned in the post. 

`conda install -c bioconda multiqc`

This is how I solved the problem. Thank you for answering